# Locally removed files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I deleted a few local files that seemed to have been tracked in Mercurial, so I get:

```
ga1009@ga1009-dell:~/PhD/equilibrium$ hg status -q
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/CVaR_vs_loan.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/CVaR_vs_noMargin.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/CVaR_vs_xi.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/defaults_loan3.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/defaults_loan6.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/loansBeforeDefault_loan10.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/loansBeforeDefault_loan3.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/pnl_loan6.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/pnl_loan6_alt.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/simulation.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/values_loan10.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Matlab_ga/values_loan3.p~
! equilibrium/Computations/Vidur_120330/Chebyshev2value.m
! equilibrium/Computations/Vidur_120330/t=12.fig
! equilibrium/Computations/Vidur_120330/t=2.fig
! equilibrium/Computations/Vidur_120330/t=25.fig
```

Is there a way to remove these without adding anything to the repository? I have loads of files that should not be added, so using `hg addremove` is just not an option. I tried to do `hg forget` on each of these files, but I get `equilibrium/Computations/Vidur_120330/t=25.fig: No such file or directory` -- which is not a big surprise given that these are deleted. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. At least it doesn't happen normally. Both `hg remove` and `hg forget` should work AFAIK.

Comment: @Jon, found out the problem. I was running it from a subfolder of my repository, and these paths are relative to the root obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can revert your WC and delete files in Mercurial-way

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hg remove --after` for this. It will remove files from the repo after you've already deleted them from disk.

Type `hg help remove` at the command line for more info.